# Getting IsolatedStorageException when trying to create directory in windows phone application

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, isolatedstorage, isolatedstoragefile

Here is my code.

```csharp
var storage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
if (!directoryPath.StartsWith("/"))
            directoryPath = "/" + directoryPath;

if (!storage.DirectoryExists(directoryPath))
{
    storage.CreateDirectory(directoryPath);
}
```

Sometimes I am getting following exception when I call this method.

```
[Type]:[IsolatedStorageException]    
[ExceptionMessage]:[Unable to create directory.]
```

I don't know why I am getting this exception. Is there any problem in my code? It is working fine many times but some times I am getting exception.

Please let me know what is the problem in my code.

Comment: Why adding the Slash ("/")?

Comment: It is just for specifying directory path.I am facing same problem even I remove Slash.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error message.  It turns out that I was using the full directory path when I should have just been using the folder name.

After I changed it to just the last folder name it stopped throwing this exception.